# how to convert hour to seconds in swift?

Tags: swift, integer

I need to convert this code to an hours

```
func convert_to_seconds(hours: Int) -> Int {
    // write your code here
    }
```

the input is:

```
 hours = 6
```

the output is:

```
 21600
```

I tried several codes but they didn't work for me

Comment: What have you tried? How did it not work?

Comment: Well considering that an hour contains 3600 seconds your output seems fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func convert_to_seconds(hours: Int) -> Int {
    hours*3600
}
```